# How do I modify the Windows 10 File Explorer 'New item' menu?

Tags: windows

This is the menu I mean:

[image: New item menu]

I want to be able to add and delete items. Thanks for your assistance.

This is **not** a context menu (sometimes known as a right-click menu). It's the drop-down menu available near the top of the File Explorer display, under 'New Item'.

[image: Look for 'New Item' with downward arrow.]

How can I change its items?

Comment: @AndrewL You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to edit the registry to add and remove entries in the New Context Menu:

Navigate to the Registry editor first by opening the run prompt (<kbd>Windows+R</kbd>) then type `regedit` and press enter.

**Removing an entry**

1. Navigate to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and expand it.
2. Look for the extension of the file-type you want to remove from the menu. For example, if you want to remove "New Word Document", find `.docx` and expand it.
3. In the sub-keys, find the key `ShellNew` and remove it. This will remove the entry.

[image]

**Adding an entry**

1. Navigate to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and expand it.
2. Look for the extension of the file-type you want to add to the menu. For example, if you want to add the entry "New XML Document", find `.xml`.
3. Right click on it and select `New -> Key` and name it `ShellNew`.
4. In the right pane select `New -> String Value`. Name it `NullFile` and press enter.

If the above does not work (as it does sometimes on certain files on newer Windows versions), try the following:

5. Navigate to `C:\Windows\ShellNew` and create a new file (with any name) with the extension of file-type you want to add. For example, if you want `.xml`:

[image]

6. Go back to the registry editor where you created `NullFile` in step 4. In there, create another string value named `FileName` and set it to the path you created in step 5:

[image]

The file-type should now show up in the New Context Menu.

---

All information and images found [here](https://www.google.com/amp/www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-items-from-new-context-menu/amp?client=safari) and [here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-add-remove-items-from-new-menu-in-windows/). Check links for further reading.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Unfortunately I didn't make myself clear. I wasn't referring to the *context menu* for a folder (or file) but to the menu associated with the item available near the top of the display in the Windows 10 File Explorer. I've amended my question to show where it appears.

Comment: @BillBell Oh, I see what you mean. AFAIK they seem to be the same thing.

Comment: One might expect that but they aren't on the computer I'm using. If I right click on one of the folders I'm offered the opportunity to create a folder. If I click on 'New item' I can create one of several types of files or a shortcut or a folder. There are other file types I'd like to be able to create this easily.

Comment: @BillBell The New Context Menu corresponds to the menu you see when you right click on a directory and hover over new, and the new item dropdown you see IIRC

Comment: I hate it when this happens. I right-clicked on a directory and hovered over 'new' -- and it says 'Folder'. I'd much prefer to have it do what I think you were predicting. :)

Comment: @BillBell Is it possible to show some pictures? That's quite strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50746/discussion-between-bill-bell-and-andrew-l).

Comment: `C:\Windows\ShellNew` does not seem to exist on my PC