# 'New item' context menu not using template to create new files

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to add entries to the *New* context menu using information found for example here: [How do I modify the Windows 10 File Explorer 'New item' menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1160380/how-do-i-modify-the-windows-10-file-explorer-new-item-menu)

My problem is when I try to add entries that require a template to properly create the new file. My first problem was that there was no `C:\Windows\ShellNew` folder (with *hidden* and *protected operating system files* displayed) so I created the `ShellNew` folder. I then added my template files to that folder, navigated to the file extensions in RegEdit then created the `NullFile` and `FileName` string values as described in the above question with the `FileName` value saying `%SystemRoot%\ShellNew\Template.7z`.

However, when I then create a new file using that context menu, the process is not using the template files I pointed to in the `FileName` value. Instead, it is creating an empty file that doesn't work because it is missing data that causes the program associated with it to label the new file as corrupt.

Here is a screenshot comparing the template file to the new file that is supposed to be based on that template:
[image: Comparison]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem after some tinkering. If you put your template files in the `C:\Windows\ShellNew` folder, you don't need to add that part of the file path to the registry key's `FileName` value. So, in my case, instead of putting `%SystemRoot%\ShellNew\Template.7z` in that string value, I would write `Template.7z`.